# Building a text indexer from scratch, need algorithms and resources

Tags: full-text-search

I am making a simple text search engine for self-study. I already coded by myself some of the work in 'Anatomy of a Search Engine' at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/AnatomyOfASearchEngine1.aspx

It featured searching with inverted indexes.

I want to do more projects, better search algorithms. The online resources at my level are hard to find. please point me to more resources I can look up, so that I can get hands-on experience.

I may use this in production in the future (for simple purposes).